# Dictionary loading in background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dictionary, backgroundworker

This seems like it should be so simple, but apparently it isn't.

I have a dictionary that needs to load ~40,000 entries on program startup.
It only delays load time by about 5-7 seconds, but I'd like to do it in the background to avoid this.

In the code below, there are 3 sections that deal with the `dictionary` and `BackgroundWorker`I currently have.

I know that this code makes it to the `PopulateZipCodeDictionary()` method, but for some reason it doesn't actually launch that method.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    static BackgroundWorker populateZipCodeDictionary;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        populateZipCodeDictionary = new BackgroundWorker();
        populateZipCodeDictionary.DoWork += populateZipCodeDictionary_DoWork;
        populateZipCodeDictionary.RunWorkerCompleted += populateZipCodeDictionary_RunWorkerCompleted;
        populateZipCodeDictionary.RunWorkerAsync();         
    }

    static void populateZipCodeDictionary_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        ZipCodes.PopulateZipCodeDictionary();
    }

    static void populateZipCodeDictionary_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dictionary loaded");
    }
```

---

```
static class ZipCodes
{
    #region Methods
    public static string GetValue(string key)
    {
        string result;
        if (zipCodeDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region ZipCode Dictionary Definition
    static Dictionary<string, string> zipCodeDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void PopulateZipCodeDictionary()
    {
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00501", "Holtsville, NY" );
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00544", "Holtsville, NY" );
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00601", "Adjuntas, PR" );
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00602", "Aguada, PR" );
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00603", "Aguadilla, PR" );
        zipCodeDictionary.Add( "00604", "Aguadilla, PR" );
        //Continues on adding ~40k entries...
    }
```

Comment: That looks correct, if you put a `Debug.WriteLine()` inside the `PopulateZipCodeDictionary()` method does it get called? Are any expections being thrown by that method? You also might want to move the zipcodes to either a database or text file and read instead of having them all hard coded as it would be much easier to keep the up to date and reduce the code by 40k lines as well.

Comment: what type of debugging have you done in the ZipCode class, any code omitted, have you stepped through it?

Comment: I placed a breakpoint at the first of the zipCodeDictionary.Add statements, and it never triggered.

Comment: Place a break point on the ZipCodes.PopulateZipCodeDictionary() line then step into the code, does that work?

Comment: Just out of interest, what version of Visual Studio and .Net are you using? Are you running it in the debugger or do you have a test harness?

Comment: I've done the step into, thats what's confusing.  And versions are Vs 2010 and .Net 4.0

Comment: So what happened when you stepped into the class, then stepped over each method? I created a mock app using your code and everything appeared to work fine.

Comment: I did try that, and it didn't throw any exceptions or anything, it just wasn't populating the list.  I honestly don't know what was wrong with my code, but when I tried Jordan's method it did work, so I kind of just ignored the problems and went his route.  :)

Comment: If you don't mind, send me a zip of your test code minus any IP. My email is in my profile. I'd like to see if I can replicate the behavior your are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a routine I use for background processing.  You simply give `RunBehind` an action to perform and an action to call when processing is complete.

```
public class Worker
{
    private Dispatcher _appDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    private Dispatcher _workerDispatcher;
    private Thread _workerThread;

    public Worker()
    {
        _workerThread = new Thread(RunWorkerThread);
        _workerThread.Start();
    }

    public void RunBehind(Action a_action, Action a_callback)
    {
        _workerDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            a_action();
            _appDispatcher.BeginInvoke(a_callback);
        }));
    }

    private void RunWorkerThread()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "AppWorker";
        _workerDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

        Dispatcher.Run();
    }
}
```

Also maybe try locking...

```
static class ZipCodes
{
    private static Object zipLocker = new Object();

    #region Methods
    public static string GetValue(string key)
    {
        lock (zipLocker)
        {
            string result;
            if (zipCodeDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion


    #region ZipCode Dictionary Definition
    static Dictionary<string, string> zipCodeDictionary = null;

    public static void PopulateZipCodeDictionary()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> workingDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        workingDictionary.Add( "00501", "Holtsville, NY" );
        workingDictionary.Add( "00544", "Holtsville, NY" );
        workingDictionary.Add( "00601", "Adjuntas, PR" );
        workingDictionary.Add( "00602", "Aguada, PR" );
        workingDictionary.Add( "00603", "Aguadilla, PR" );
        workingDictionary.Add( "00604", "Aguadilla, PR" );
        //Continues on adding ~40k entries...

        lock (zipLocker)
        {
            zipCodeDictionary = workingDictionary;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is an awesome method you've created.  It definitely simplifies this aspect of c#.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad.  I love C#.  I just wished the Dispatcher could be used in Silverlight. Maybe in Silverlight 5.

Answer (score 1):

I see only two cases:

1. `DoWork` event handler was actually executed and you somehow missed that, putting a break point would be most efficient way to see what actually is going on
2. Some issue was raised so `RunWorkerCompleted` event was raised with an error in event args

MSDN, [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx)

> Occurs when the background operation has completed, has been canceled,
>   or has raised an exception.
>   The Error property of
>   System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs indicates that an
>   exception was thrown by the operation

Comment: 1. Yes it is executed, just the method inside it doesn't execute.    2. VS Debugger didn't throw any errors.  And the thing is, the dictionary is not searchable/empty when this is all done.  The MessageBox command is purely to see if/when the worker thread is completed.

Comment: Enable please CLR exceptions in Visual Studio menu `Debug -> Exceptions` and launch application again, any exceptions now?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your completed event handler to this:

```
static void populateZipCodeDictionary_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Dictionary loaded");
}
```

My guess is that your DoWork handler is throwing an exception.

Comment: How would I be able to see that exception?  I would assume that BS would point out that exception when it occurs, right?

Comment: If you mean VS (Visual Studio) and you run the app under the debugger, it should break when the exception occurs.

Comment: Yeah, that was meant to be VS...awesome typo huh?  ;). And no exceptions are being thrown there